# How to open a modal after a success axios request

Tags: reactjs

I have a class component (Contact.js) who has the functionality of send a POST request (using axios) to another app that I have (in Node using Nodemailer) and that app send a email. Its works fine, but I don't know how to open a Modal (or Toast) if the response of the request is ok. To be more clear this is my component (I remove several lines of code who don't matter for this problem so the code is smaller so if u see that something is missing don't worry the app send the request ok, the response come ok and the mail is sent).

In the ``response === "success"``` I want to open a modal, but it doesn't work (I'm pretty new of React so I don't know what I'm doing wrong)

```
class Contact extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: "",
      email: "",
      message: "",
      subject: "",
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Styles>
        <Container id={this.props.id} className="contenedor">
          <Form
            id="contact-form"
            onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}
            method="POST"
          >
            <Row className="fila">
              <Col sm={12} md={6}>
                <Form.Group>
                  <Form.Label htmlFor="name">Nombre</Form.Label>
                  <Form.Control
                    required
                    type="text"
                    className="form-control"
                    placeholder="Ingrese su nombre"
                    value={this.state.name}
                    onChange={this.onNameChange.bind(this)}
                  />
                </Form.Group>
                
                ..ANOTHER THREE FORM.GROUP FOR EMAIL SUBJECT AND MESSAGE

                <Button type="submit" className="btn btn-dark btn-block">
                  Enviar
                </Button>
              </Col>
            </Row>
          </Form>
        </Container>
      </Styles>
    );
  }

  onNameChange(e) {
    this.setState({ name: e.target.value });
  }

  ... THE SAME HERE OF ABOVE, ANOTHER THREE FUNCTIONS FOR EMAIL, SUBJECT AND MESSAGE   

  resetForm() {
    this.setState({ name: "", email: "", message: "", subject: "" });
  }

  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    axios({
      method: "POST",
      url: "https://itis-mailer.herokuapp.com/send",
      data: this.state,
    }).then((response) => {
      if (response.data.status === "success") {
        <Modal.Dialog>
          <Modal.Header closeButton>
            <Modal.Title>Exito</Modal.Title>
          </Modal.Header>

          <Modal.Body>
            <p>La consulta fue enviada.</p>
          </Modal.Body>
        </Modal.Dialog>;
        this.resetForm();
      } else if (response.data.status === "fail") {
        alert("Error al enviar el mensaje");
      }
    });
  }
}

export default Contact;
```

Comment: Your modal related code should definitely be inside your `JSX` that's returned in the `render` method. What UI component library are you using specifically and does the `Modal.Dialog` component take a `boolean` as a `prop` that allows you to show or hide as needed?

Comment: I'm using React Bootstrap for the Modal.Dialog. I'm gonna see if I have that prop available

Comment: I think I may use the prop `show`, this is the doc (https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/modal/#modal-dialog-props) and is inside `Modal`

Comment: Yes, that sounds like it.

Comment: I'm gonna try for myself, but if u want and can, can u show me a simple example of this? In the case I don't know how to do it or if I can make it but is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `handleSubmit` could be inside your component class so you could set a state for open a modal

Something like:

```js
class Contact extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      modalIsOpen: false,
    };
  }

  handleSubmit() {
    axios.call()
      .then(() => this.setState({
        modalIsOpen: true
      }));
  }
  render() {
    return ( 
      <>
        <modal isOpen={modalIsOpen}/>  
        <form>
        /* foo */
        </form>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm gonna try this, but the Modal component has a prop `show`, if I set to `true` the modal shows or not in case of `false`. One think I don't understand in your code, what is that `isOpen` handler?

Comment: This code work fine adapting it to my code. I add a prop `showModal` and set in false in the constructor. Then using the prop `show` that comes with the component `Modal` of `react-bootstrap` make this: `<Modal show={this.state.showModal}>` and in the repsonse of axion change for this: `if (response.data.status === "success") {this.setState({showModal: true,});`

Thank you man, works great!

Comment: It was just an example, the prop `show` is the one we are looking for

Answer (score 0):

You can open the model through state.

***demo code:-***

Code only to understand

```
function Example() {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

  const handleClose = () => setShow(false);

return(
    <>
    <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
           <Modal.Header closeButton> .... </Modal.Header>
        </Model>
    </>
    )


axios({
    method: "POST",
    url: "https://itis-mailer.herokuapp.com/send",
    data: this.state,
}).then((response) => {
    if (response.data.status === "success") {
        setShow(true)
        this.resetForm();
    } else if (response.data.status === "fail") {
        alert("Error al enviar el mensaje");
    }
});
```